# How can I change Content-Length in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to change Content-Length of my request, as I see by default it's "168". Also I would know what used Content-Length for. Some sites give me net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH (e.g. api sites) so I hope I can fix that and also I would know what is that error (mentioned upper). And do I need to change it or there another way of fixing it?

I tried this but it didn't worked at all:

```py
import requests
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({ "Content-length": "2" })
session.post("https://example.com/")
```

Comment: Try to use like this : `session.headers.update({"Content-Length": "2"})`. Please let me know if it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what used Content-Length for.

From [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945)

> When an Entity-Body is included with a message, the length of that body may be determined in one of two ways. If a Content-Length header field is present, its value in bytes represents the length of the Entity-Body. Otherwise, the body length is determined by the closing  of the connection by the server.
>
> Closing the connection cannot be used to indicate the end of a request body, since it leaves no possibility for the server to send back a response. Therefore, HTTP/1.0 requests containing an entity body must include a valid Content-Length header field. If a request contains an entity body and Content-Length is not specified, and the server does not recognize or cannot calculate the length from other fields, then the server should send a 400 (bad request) response.

therefore value in `Content-Length` should describe size (in bytes) of body of given request.

```
session.headers.update({ "Content-length": "2" })
session.post("https://example.com/")
```

This piece of code is mutually exclusive, you at same time inform server to expect 2 bytes body and then send bodyless requests. If you wish to send bodyless request and Content-Length, value of it should be zero (`{"Content-length":"0"}`)

Answer (score 4):

*Content-Length* is the byte size of the HTTP request or response body. In your case, it's the byte size of the HTTP POST data. The Python *request* [.post call](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.post) takes the `data=` or `json=` argument, from which *request* automatically computes and specifies the *Content-Length* in the HTTP request.

When using Python *requests*, there is no need to specify *Content-Length* manually, doing so won't have any benefits, and it can be a source of errors.

Please specify `data=` or `json=` though to your `.post(...)` call. Or use a `.get(...)` call instead.